# Contest problem(Combinatorics//maybe DP)

Tags: combinatorics, dynamic-programming

**Problem :**

There are n people in a party. Each person can either join dance as a single individual or as a pair with any other. Find the number of different ways in which all n people can join the dance.

Input data
One integer n (1 ≤ n ≤ 10^5).

Output data
Print the number of different ways in which all n people can join the dance. Print the answer modulo 10^9 + 7.

**Let we have n = 3 people. They can dance in 4 ways: {1, 2, 3}, {{1, 2}, 3}, {1, {2, 3}}, {{1, 3}, 2}.**

**If question is easy, Sorry.**

I think answer equivalent with number of pairs in party :

I divide problem to 3 parts:

All are single in party .--> +1

There is only one pair --> n * (n - 1) / 2

Other cases that are some pairs --> **I need help here.**

**answer = n * (n - 1) / 2 + Other cases + 1**

I calculated these:

n = 3 : 3 + 0 + 1;

n = 4: 6 + 3 + 1;

n = 5: 10 + 15 + 1 ;

n = 6: 15 + 15 + 1;

Comment: Separating the easy edge cases isn't useful if you don't have a solution for the case where there are two or more pairs.

Comment: Have you heard of recurrence relations?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes I used recursion;

Comment: "*Yes I used recursion*"  If you did then you should already have your answer.  What did you get?

Comment: What is the source of this problem?  Reduction $\pmod {10^9+7}$ is typically done in coding challenges.

Comment: @lulu I write solution for n = 3 in problem

Comment: $n=3$ is not the only small number.  If you have a recursion, you should easily be able to compute the first $20$ or so values.

Comment: @JMoravitz , Sorry, I misunderstood, no I didn't use recursion in this question.I will try it

Comment: @lulu ,Source is https://www.eolymp.com/en/problems/11288

Comment: The punchline for the suggested recurrence approach is that if you have $n$ people, then the $n$'th person can either join on their own or find someone else to dance with.  Then you have fewer people still needing to join the dance floor.  This is a very well known problem that goes by many names and many flavors with a well known solution: https://oeis.org/A000085
With regards to the programming aspect, it just remains that you need to try to be efficient with it to be able to handle the arithmetic when you get to such large numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, there is also a direct counting argument.

Think about how many ways there are to form $k$ pairs. Note that $k$ must be between $0$ and $\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor$, inclusive. For the first pair, there are $n$ choices for the first person and $n - 1$ choices for the second person. However, we don't care which person is "first" and "second", just that they are a pair. So that gives $\frac{n (n - 1)}{2}$ ways to form the first pair. Forming subsequent pairs is equally easy. For the $m$th pair, there are $n - 2 m + 2$ people from which to pick. So, there are $\frac{(n - 2 m + 2) (n - 2 m + 1)}{2}$ ways to select the pair.

However, just as we don't care which person is "first" in a pair, we also don't care about the order in which the pairs are formed. So, we will divide the product by $k!$.

The result is

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor} \frac{1}{k! 2^k} \frac{n!}{(n - 2 k)!}$$

Comment: While not wrong, I would expect this approach to be very costly in terms of computing power required, noting that $n$ can be relatively large here.  Addition is typically cheaper than multiplication, and there is a lot of multiplying and dividing going on here.

Comment: Have you tried implementing this?  I'd be surprised if this was faster than the cheap recursion, but maybe there are some efficiencies.

Comment: @JMoravitz Definitely. Just wanted to offer this approach as a way to directly count the number of cases. I do not suggest it be used to numerically compute values, especially for large $n$.

Comment: @lulu No, I have not. I also don't expect that this will be faster than recursion.

Comment: Thanks, Solution is very interesting, I shall try to implement it(Of course,maybe I have problem with time limit .